# Сложность сортировки слиянием

Tags: java

Взял я сортировку слиянием, мне надо посчитать сложность по количеству итераций, но у меня почему то не совпадает. Например, для массива длины 16, количество итераций должно быть 64.
Подскажите в чем и где ошибка?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class M {

    private static int[] aux;//вспомогательный массив для слияний
    public static long kol = 0;

    public static void sort(int [] a) {
        aux = new int [a.length];
        sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    private static void sort(int [] a, int lo, int hi) {
        kol++;
        if (hi <= lo) {
            return;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(a, lo, mid);//сортировка левой половины
        sort(a, mid + 1, hi);//сортировка правой половины
        merge(a, lo, mid, hi);//слияние результатов
    }

    public static void merge(int[] a, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
        for (int k = 0; k <= hi; k++) {//копирование a[lo..hi] в aux[lo..hi]
            aux[k] = a[k];
            kol++;
        }

        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {//слияние назад в a[lo.. hi]
            kol++;
            if (i > mid) {
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            } else if (j > hi) {
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            } else if (aux[j]<(aux[i]) ) {
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            } else {
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        int[] p = new int [16];

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            p[i] = 10 - i;

        }

        sort(p);

        System.out.println(kol);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
           System.out.println(p[i]);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Что есть *итерация* в вашем представлении? Грубо говоря, можете ли вы точно сформулировать задачу, которую вы решаете?

> Как я понимаю, вы получили `64,` подставив ваше `N` в формулу `? = N log2 N`. То есть, неформально говоря, вы вычислили **количество константных операций,** которое требуется для завершения работы алгоритма `MERGESORT,` для которого, в свою очередь, известна алгоритмическая сложность `Θ(N log N)`).

- Если это и есть *итерация* в вашем представлении, то вычислить их общее количество несложно. Алгоритм `MERGESORT` работает следующим образом:

  ```
  def MERGESORT:
      MERGESORT(LOW)
      MERGESORT(HIGH)
      MERGE(LOW, HIGH)
  ```

> - Время работы `MERGESORT` можно выразить как `T(N) = 2 * T(N / 2) + N`, поскольку он рекурсивно запускается для двух половин последовательности, а после этого за `N` операций выполняет их слияние.
> - Для того, чтобы вычислить количество этих самых *операций* (или *итераций* в вашей формулировке), то вам нужно на каждый вызов `MERGE` увеличивать общее число операций `TOTAL` на `K`, где `K` — суммарный размер последовательностей `LOW` и `HIGH,` пришедших на вход `MERGE(LOW, HIGH)`.

- В связи с вышенаписанным, не очень понятно, почему вы увеличиваете `kol` в трех разных местах и чем вы, собственно, руководствовались, когда решили это сделать `:)`

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, IMHO TC просто число пересылок (а на сравнения внимания не обращает) считает за итерации, поскольку на каждом шаге обоих циклов (каждой *итерации*) одна пересылка элемента.

Answer (score 1):

По моему вот здесь

```
 private static void sort(int [] a, int lo, int hi) {
    kol++;
    ....
```

лишний подсчет.

А вообще в mergesort есть маленькая хитрость. В  `aux` можно копировать **только** `lo` половину. И места под `aux[]` в этом случае  надо только `a.length / 2 + 1`. Это справедливо, т.к. перед `merge` Вы *сами всегда* делите массив пополам.

Почему-то (может из-за парадигмы написания как можно более универсальных функций?) в популярной учебной литературе об этом не упоминается.

Потом сливаете в результат (младший из aux, младший из `hi` половины).

Надеюсь понятно.

**Update**

Что-то я засомневался, какую половину лучше копировать (занимался как-то этим вопросом). Посмотрел у себя и обнаружил, что все правильно, копируем первую (`lo, mid`).